# How can I improve the quality of sound in Ubuntu?

Tags: sound, 14.04

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and I'm loving it. Only thing is that I'm having problems with my laptop's sound quality. It sounds empty, or hollow. I'm not exactly sure how to put it to words, but it's noticeably worse than it was on Windows 8.1. In fact, it was very much above average on Windows. I like Ubuntu but this sound quality issue is really annoying me, and even giving me a headache at times. It's not as loud as it should. If I put up the volume to 100%, my laptop's speakers start to resonate and distort, just sounds terrible overall.

**Background info:**

I have an HP Envy TS-15 /w Altec Lansing, in Windows it had BEATS audio drivers.It has 2 front speakers, 2 subwoofers, and one speaker on the bottom of the laptop.

Comment: Yup - This helped a lot!
After installing PulseAudio, just set the preset to "Laptop".
It sounds a lot better, although not quite as good.

Answer (score 21):

The link from one of the comments helped a lot.

**Go to this site:**
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/system-wide-pulseaudio-equalizer.html

**-Or-**

Put the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-equalizer
```

Afterwards, search for "PulseAdudio", you'll see a window with a drop-down option for "Presets", click that, and select "Laptop".
Helped me significantly!

Comment: My PC randomly had severe sound distortion. I installed this and toggled the equalizer on/off and it somehow fixed it o_o